# Sending Message Requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am making a chat application using *Socket.IO* and *Node.JS*. I would like to implement message requests, such as the ones [Facebook's Messenger](http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Facebook-Messenger-for-iOS-Filtered-Requests-iPhone-screenshot-003.png) has. I am not sure how to go about this problem.

If *Mike* wants to send a private message to *Jake*, *Jake* must first accept *Mike*'s message request. Let's say *Mike* connects to the server using *Socket.IO*, and the server handles his request. Mike can then send sockets to the server, for example, a chat socket such as the one below:

```
socket.emit( 'chat', { // Emits the 'chat' socket to the server
    name: 'Mike', // Sets the name of the sender
    receiver: 'Jake', // Sets the name of the receiver
    message: 'Hey Jake!' // Sets the message
} );
```

Now, obviously, this socket should be sent **IF ANY ONLY IF** *Jake* accepted the message request already. This is where the problem lies.
Message requests are stored in a database ( this is necessary for my application ).

I have a few ideas in mind on how to accomplish this:

1. Query the database each time a user sends a *chat* socket, to see if the receiver accepted the sender's request. Of course, this would mean that each time a chat is sent, I have a database query. This seems **highly** inefficient to me.
2. Query the database once somehow, and allow chat messages to go through without issuing a database query every time - although I am *not* sure how to accomplish this - hence this question.

I would love your input on this problem. Thanks!

Comment: See if this helps: https://medium.com/@danielsternlicht/caching-like-a-boss-in-nodejs-9bccbbc71b9b

Comment: @PM77-1 Interesting, I'll give it a read in a minute :)

Answer (score 0):

The request you mentioned, is that request accepting should happen just once, like in facebook or it should be accepted for every message sent.

I hope it is just once, when the first message is sent. If this is the case then you can create a JSON file with an array containing Jake's friends(people accepted by Jake). Whenever someone tries to send a message to Jake, you just refer to the JSON files Jake's array to see if the sender is in the array list. If yes you can proceed with broadcasting message to Jake. If not in the array, send Jake a connection request from sender(Mike).

Since you are storing message requests in database, update the JSON file arrays when ever a new connection request is accepted by some one.

I hope this helps you. Comment below, if I am out of your scope anywhere.

Comment: The request should be only sent once, yes. I have thought about doing something along those lines, but post-production having such info in files seems relatively error-prone - caching sounds like a safer alternative.

Comment: If you prefer caching that's the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways.

1) You can have caching done (as mentioned by @PM-77-1) which helps decrease number of database queries. Redis cache is really easy to use with Node.js. So whenever you are trying to check if Mike has Jake as a friend you can first check at cache level if Jake is in Mike's friend list. If Mike's friend list is not available you can fetch it from db once and store it in cache for future use.

2) You can also allow a user (Mike) to send around 100 to 200 short messages (just an example) and the messages are hidden for Jake until Jake accepts Mike's request. Having a limit on number of messages Mike can send without being a friend is a subjective question and it depends upon how famous application it is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I am most likely going to do caching to solve this issue. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but I think your second idea is a bit inefficient, in terms of storage space and expandability :)

Comment: It's a subjective debate. Most of the companies try to be friendly to user so they don't like stopping users from taking some action, rather after the action they show them a nice message mentioning the person won't be receiving it right away. Whatsapp is like that, Facebook has done that before. Also storage is not a big issue when it's a textual data. Image and video files are still considered as a concern.